# Resize a DIV based on Mousewheel spin

Tags: jquery

i am trying to "resize" a  called "view" based on the mouse wheel spin.
For down spin the  size should be decreased and for up spin the size should be increased. 
I don't have any idea to do it. Please someone help me to achieve it.
Here is my HTML code..

```
<div class="main"><div class="view"></div></div>
```

and my jQuery code is

```
$('.view').css('height','100px')
$('.view').css('width','100px')
$('.view').css('background-color','blue')
$('.view').mousewheel(function()
              {
                  alert('Hello');
              });
```

I think it is wrong way of doing. Hope i will get help.

Comment: Are you sure you want the `<div>` element to *shrink* when the mouse wheel is rolled *down*? IMHO, natural eye-to-hand coordination would suggest to enlarge it instead, and to shrink it when the mouse wheel is rolled *up*.

Comment: I feel the opposite, rolling up implies zooming in. Like your browser zoom (usually ctrl+mwu).

Comment: @Marc, excellent point. I was thinking about *sliding* more than *zooming* from some reason (since the element position does not change). To each his own, I guess :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.view').css('height', '100');
$('.view').css('width', '100');
$('.view').css('background-color', 'blue');
$('.view').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
    var delta_px = delta > 0 ? "+=50" : "-=50";
    $(this).css('width', delta_px);
});
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/scpDH/

Comment: `$(this).css('width', delta_px);` probably makes more sense.

Comment: @Dogbert your answer is perfect but after some down scrolls it is completely vanishing <div> How can i prevent it up to some height and width.

Comment: @Reddy, you can simply put in an if condition to see if the `delta < 0 && currentwidth < 100`, and not do anything.

Comment: @Dogbert btw - it is good to place `return false` at end of fuction (after `$(this).css('width', delta_px);`)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/scpDH/7/
some fixes on that sample (used this) and added acceleration

Answer (score 1):

There are plugins for this, for example have a look at [this](http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/demos) demo page.

Answer (score 1):

You could do (assuming you have the [mousewheel](http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/demos) extension):

```
$('.view').css('height', '100px')
$('.view').css('width', '100px')
$('.view').css('background-color', 'blue');
var step = 10;

$('.view').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
    var movement = 0;
    var dir = delta > 0 ? true : false,
        vel = Math.abs(delta);
    var height = parseInt($('.view').css('height'), 10);
    var width = parseInt($('.view').css('width'), 10);
    if (dir === true) {
        movement += step;
    } else {
        movement -= step;
    }
    console.log(movement);
    $('.view').css('height',height + movement );
    $('.view').css('width',width+ movement );

});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/yTEJL/